# Real time input value from angularjs , for ulr http.get

Tags: angularjs

$http.get('example.com/api/json/'+'input.value') in angularjs controller function and updating {{data}} according to input

```js
var id="de1cfb221f978cebde0db9adfb5da6b9";
var city ="London";

angular.module('moo', [])
.controller('mooAngular', function($scope, $http) {

    $http.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?' +
    'q=' +city +

     '&appid=' + id
    ).
        then(function(response) {
            $scope.myData = response.data


        });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" ng-app="moo" ng-controller="mooAngular" ng-init="">
<p>T(K) ={{myData.main.temp}}&deg;</p>
<input id="city" type="text" ng-change="city" name="city" placeholder="Enter name here" value="">
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You should make your post more precise. What is your question? What is the result of your code? What is the desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want dynamic value for URL, you can use "$scope":

```
var id="de1cfb221f978cebde0db9adfb5da6b9";
var city ="London";

angular.module('moo', [])
.controller('mooAngular', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.city = city;
    $scope.$watch('city', function(){
      console.log($scope.city);  
    });

    $http.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?' + 'q=' +$scope.city + '&appid=' + id
    ).then(function(response) {
      $scope.myData = response.data;
    });
});
```

Also, you can update following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="moo">
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <div class="container"  ng-controller="mooAngular">
      <p>T(K) ={{myData.main.temp}}&deg;</p>
      <input id="city" type="text"  ng-model="city" placeholder="Enter name here" >
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here goes working plnkr:

https://plnkr.co/edit/uDG73ajQ0Ab9iPFIaIVU?p=preview

I've used watch in controller, just to show that city value is being updated. You can customise/move your $http request in $watch as well.

IMHO you should use dropdown with names of cities instead of input, by that you can directly hit the weather server, or else you will have to verify city names as well.

**Updated Snippet, with get request inside $watch:**

```
var id="de1cfb221f978cebde0db9adfb5da6b9";
var city ="London";

angular.module('moo', [])
.controller('mooAngular', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.city = city;
    $scope.$watch('city', function(){
      console.log($scope.city);  
      $http.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?' + 'q=' +$scope.city + '&appid=' + id)
        .then(function(response) {
          $scope.myData = response.data;
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I have already done like that , when fulfilled input ,  data is not synchronized.